# Ctrix VDI's - keeping them power on by passing user input through scripts?

Tags: windows, powershell, citrix, vdi, vbx

This question is about Citrix VDI's. If there is a better place  other than SOF then plz suggest, I will be happy to move it there. ( like https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for unix/linux questions or https://askubuntu.com/ for ubuntu/debian questions)

I am using citix window 10 VDI. The issue is, if i leave the VDI inactive for 2 hours it disconnects and if I don't connect back with in 2 hours of disconnection it will power off i.e shutdown. This auto power off i.e auto shutdown feature is causing me lot of issue as my background programs are getting terminated in between and I am not able to progress. My IT team can not help me with auto power off, but they suggested me that if I can mimic user input through scripts like powershell or VBX scripts etc then the disconnection and shutdown can be avoided.

I am not aware of any such scripts, does anyone know of any such scripts in powershell or VBX or any other language that can mimic user input like mouse movement etc and say you OS/Windows 10 that the user is active.

Please do help you have any idea, that would be quite a saver for me.

*(Please don't suggest me on the side effects like missing windows updates or other updates etc or IT costs etc.. as we have considered all those already and for some period of time we decided to find a way to avoid the auto shutdown feature. Thanks for understanding)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idle Disconnect and Logoff Timers in Windows Desktop VDAs can be set with policies such as described [here](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX205501/how-to-configure-idle-disconnect-and-logoff-timers-in-xendesktop-7x-for-windows-desktop-vdas?recommended).

To mimic user input and prevent idle/disconnect timers to kick in you can use [Caffeine](https://github.com/andyjmorgan/CaffeineForCitrixWorkspace).